Python skimage: Turning grayscale image array into float makes the image use color instead of grayscale
When using the skimage.io module in python to read an image in grayscale, it works as intended. However, doing anything to the numpy array holding the values which results in them changing to float makes the scale a color gradient rather than grayscale.
This is a problem for me since I need to divide each entry of the array by 255, which automatically turns each value into float.
I am sure there is a way for me to fix this, but I am more curious as to why this happens in the first place.
I first tested to see if this was just an issue with dividing the values in general, but I tested it by taking the array and:
-multiplying it by one, which resulted in the intended grayscale image
-dividing it by one, which resulted in the color gradient image
Code that works as intended -
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

a=io.imread("audrey_lnoise.png",as_gray=True)
io.imshow(a)

Output - Intended Image
Altered code -
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

a=io.imread("audrey_lnoise.png",as_gray=True)/1 #division by one to turn into float array
io.imshow(a)

Output - Unintended image

io.imshow uses matplotlib. that's all.

Give a try to
io.imshow(a, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

